# Creating a unique key (cache key) for multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have a method that caches data based on 3 parameters. For example:

1. state
2. age
3. number of siblings.

Now I have lots of permutations in my system and they are saved in a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,MyObject> cache;
```

The dictionary's key is a concatination of the three and is done with `string.format` (something like this):

```
public string CreateKey(eState state, int age, int numberOfSibilings)
{
    return string.format("{0}#{1}#{2}", state.ToString(), age.ToString(), numberOfSibilings.ToString());
}
```

`eState` is an `enum(int)`.

The `CreateKey` method is called lots of times and is a performance barrier since `string.format` isn't extra fast and creating lot's of immutable strings isn't the best this to do.

The key can have empty entries that are replaced with a `*`. The `CreateKey` method handles them as it inputs nullables and checks if they have values.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. And since `eState` is an `int`, I thought about creating a key in a faster way with a math formula but I couldn't think about something fast and unique.

Anyway, I'm open for any solution you can offer for creating a unique key as fast and memory friendly as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.format` isn't that great when the code is performance critical. It takes parameters as `Object` type which means you need to Box your `int` and other value types.

You can create a custom struct which could be used as a Key for your dictionary. You need to implement `IEquatable<MyKey>` in your struct so that it doesn't need to be boxed when calling `Equals` method.

```
public struct MyKey : IEquatable<MyKey>
{
    public readonly eState State;
    public readonly int Age;
    public readonly int NumberOfSibilings;

   ...Implement Equals method here
}
```

Then use

```
Dictionary<MyKey ,MyObject> cache;
public MyKey CreateKey(eState state, int age, int numberOfSibilings)
{
    return new MyKey(state, age, numberOfSibilings);
}
```

This way you don't have to create many strings in your `CreateKey` method. No conversion; you just store them as int and enum itself. No calls to `Enum.ToString` which involves boxing(I guess). With our `MyKey` struct no boxing whatsoever. Which means better performance.

If you're looking for debugger friendly key(mentioned in comments), you can use `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("State= {State} Age= {Age}")]
public struct MyKey : IEquatable<MyKey>
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the answer. I liked the approach. I'm looking for some simple mathematical way to create a key (easier to debug it) and I believe there is. But this is a nice approach and it may be the final implementation :).

Comment: @AmirPopovich You mean the debugger to help you with readable key?

Comment: Yes.. I prefer not to start with hash codes and other stuff.

Comment: @AmirPopovich Updated my answer. You can use `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to format the string to be displayed in debugger. Also, hashcodes are not our enemies :)

Comment: Nice..didn't know about that feature. Anyway if I have lots of keys then 3 ints vs 1 int isn't optimistic. But thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a Tuple for your key:

`Dictionary<Tuple<eState, int, int>, MyObject> dict;`

Tuple evaluates equality like this:

- Its a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` object
- Its three components are the same type as the tuple being compared
- Each of the values are equal using the default `Equals` method.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387109(v=vs.110).aspx

The advantages are that you don't have to create a new type to hold your key, it uses the equality comparers for whatever type is in your Tuple, and is easy to use:

```
var myKey = new Tuple<eState, int, int>(eState.Whatever, 10, 15);
dict.Add(myKey, myObject)
```

Comment: +1- Thanks for the answer. The problem here is lot's of tuples = lots of memory on the heap. I prefer to go with a math formula instead.

Comment: Not sure how debugging the key isn't friendly, it shows up as `{(eState.Whatever, 10, 15)}` in the debugger. It does take up more memory though, but not necessarily on the heap.

Comment: I take back the debugger friendly thing.